# vs code custom language extension

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I am in the process of writing an extension for my own language for vs code. My problem is that I do not know how the RegEx command is to end a string with/before a semicolon.

```
“strings": {

        "name": "string.quoted.double.example",
        "begin": "(?<==).*$",  
        "end": "...",
```

Comment: Try `"begin": "=", "end": ";"`.

Comment: thnaks but i already tried this version. The beginning is fine and works, but when i try "end": ";" then everything will be colored as a string